# Editable data tables in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mean-stack

I supposed to work with data table having a large amount of data and  different fields like dropdown, date picker, autocomplete inputs in each cell.

So, I am searching for a plugin which fulfills the following features

1. Editable table - Can able to navigate by tab and edit
2. Auto fill - Some cell fields have auto complete input boxes
3. Server side pagination and sorting
4. Validation on each cell to restrict data save
5. Date picker with minimal UI
6. Infinite scroll or pagination
7. API call when i navigate to other cell in the table

I already googled with these plugins

> Angular ui-grid
>
> Jquery data tables

But, I need to know which is best among these and which fulfill my requirements

Other plugins suggestions are also appreciated

Thanks in advance